# Wha is a security parameter in a pseudorandom generator?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

F: {0,1}^λ → {0,1}^2λ is a secure pseudorandom generator, it says that λ is a security parameter, what does that mean?

Comment: Thank you! It is not a homework question, I am just very new to this and not sure where to start. Any points in the right direction? :)

Comment: Yes, G is secure

Comment: @kelalaka the standard security definition of a PRG doesn't let you "send" anything.

Comment: I was a bit unsure about what is meant by "send"

Comment: @Maeher you are right, I should talk about a distinguisher.